# pandas rank function yielding non-integers?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there any condition which would make the pandas dataframe function `rank` return a mixture of integers and floats in its return value, or are the outputs always guaranteed to be 1...N integers?

Comment: From the docstring: `Definition: df.rank(self, axis=0, numeric_only=None, method='average', na_option='keep', ascending=True)
Docstring:
Compute numerical data ranks (1 through n) along axis. Equal values are
assigned a rank that is the average of the ranks of those values
`, so not necessarily if you have multiple items with the same value.

Comment: @TomAugspurger: so the answer is no, it cannot be float then?

Comment: There can be floats. Check `df.rank()` on `df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5]})`

Comment: @TomAugspurger: Is there a way to make it assign the same integer rank not average to same rank elements? So that the output is ALWAYS just integers?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As @TomAugspurger indicates. If their are duplicates they can be non-integer. (But are of float64 dtype in any event).

```
In [7]: DataFrame({'A' : Series([1,2,3,4]), 'B' : Series([1,1,1,1]) }).rank()
Out[7]: 
   A    B
0  1  2.5
1  2  2.5
2  3  2.5
3  4  2.5

[4 rows x 2 columns]

In [8]: DataFrame({'A' : Series([1,2,3,4]), 'B' : Series([1,1,1,1]) }).rank().dtypes
Out[8]: 
A    float64
B    float64
dtype: object
```

Several rank options

```
In [12]: DataFrame({'A' : Series([1,2,3,4]), 'B' : Series([1,1,1,1]) }).rank(method='min')
Out[12]: 
   A  B
0  1  1
1  2  1
2  3  1
3  4  1

[4 rows x 2 columns]

In [13]: DataFrame({'A' : Series([1,2,3,4]), 'B' : Series([1,1,1,1]) }).rank(method='max')
Out[13]: 
   A  B
0  1  4
1  2  4
2  3  4
3  4  4

[4 rows x 2 columns]

In [14]: DataFrame({'A' : Series([1,2,3,4]), 'B' : Series([1,1,1,1]) }).rank(method='first')
Out[14]: 
   A  B
0  1  1
1  2  2
2  3  3
3  4  4

[4 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: *" If their are duplicates they can be non-integer."*. Then that's a bug, or at least there needs to be an extra option to control how ties are resolved. Only `method='average'` should ever be able to return non-integers. (Excluding of course `na_option='keep'` when NAs are returned mixed with integers, which will coerce the integers to float, which is a different issue.)

Answer (score 6):

I found the above codes yield a float solution. Probably it is a pandas version issue or some other version issue. Just as an addendum for diversity in solution, following worked as well.

```
DataFrame({'A' : Series([1,2,3,4]), 'B' : Series([1,1,1,1]) }).rank(method='min').astype(int);
```

This worked for any methods that one may use within rank.